# Setup Master-Slave replication with DML changes in Slave

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.0

I have a master database (PostgreSQL 9.0) and I need to setup a streaming replication on a slave. Slave db can read/write and make schema level changes too which shouldn't write back to master. Can you please highlight how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you only use Streaming replication, it doesn't support the write operation on the slave node. Currently,  PostgreSQL  doesn't support  multiple master itself, If you want multiple master solution,  I suggest you use [PostgreSQL-XC](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/).